# Why does `systemctl start myservice` not fork this service?

Tags: centos, systemd, systemctl

I have written a systemd service.

When I run `systemctl start foo.service`, the service starts and runs correctly, but `systemctl` does not return immediately to the shell.

After a while it exits with

```
Job for foo.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
```

and then the service is no longer running.

Here is foo.service, I RTFM and used `Type=forking` with a command which forks:

```
[Unit]
Description=blah blah

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/myservice.pid
ExecStart=/my/path/fork my-script my-args

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`my-script` does not itself fork, so `/my/path/fork` is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="$PATH:/my/path" "$@" &
```

Why does this service not fork and run in the background as expected? I have done everything as root on CentOS.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If the service doesn't fork, you can just use `Type=simple` and get on with your life. No goofy shell scripts needed.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I tried Type=simple, the `systemctl start foo` command doesn't return me to the shell.

Comment: That sounds quite strange. What is `foo`, then?

Comment: It's the placeholder for `actual-name-of-my-service`

Comment: Yes, I figured that out already. Now, what is it really?

Comment: `skls-unixuser.service` Why do you think this matters?

Answer (score 3):

Service **Type=forking** is for truly forking programs (apache for example). Your bash script only run another script on background. This is not exactly what systemd wants as forking program.
Why you using

```
Type=forking
```

, when your script my-script is normal simple service?

Try to change service type and run your script directly with this:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/var/run/myservice.pid
ExecStart=/my/path/my-script my-args
```

And **remove whole /my/path/fork** file. I can't see any profit from it.

Also you can try to set **TimeoutStartSec=1** option to service configuration file.

I'm using bash script containing infinite loop with this configuration:

```
[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/root/ha.sh
WorkingDirectory=/root/
KillSignal=SIGKILL
Restart=on-abort
Type=simple
TimeoutStartSec=1
TimeoutStopSec=1
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all
```